# PyCall unable to use pipenv version of python InitError:Incompatible `libpython` detected

Tags: python, julia, pipenv, pycall

[Following the instructions on the PyCall.jl readme](https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyCall.jl#python-virtual-environments), I am tying to use a pipenv python when using PyCall for my julia project (in it's own environment).

In a terminal, I have activated the python environment using `pipenv shell`, and then located the pathfile of the pipenv version of python. PyCall has already been added to the manifest in my julia environment. In the source-activated terminal, I started Julia and entered: `ENV["PYCALL_JL_RUNTIME_PYTHON"] = pipenv python environment`and then proceeded to run `Pkg.build("PyCall")`, [which installs conda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTKZn.jpg). When importing PyCall - `using PyCall` - I get the following error.

```
ERROR: InitError: Incompatible `libpython` detected.
`libpython` for C:\Users\me\.virtualenvs\iap\Scripts\python.exe is:
    C:\Users\me\.virtualenvs\iap\Scripts\python37.dll
`libpython` for C:\Users\me\.julia\conda\3\python.exe is:
    C:\Users\me\.julia\conda\3\python36.dll
PyCall.jl only supports loading Python environment using the same `libpython`
```

I've tried re-installing PyCall, but the python environment libpython always throws this error. How can I override or otherwise work around the conda requirement for base julia?

I have a feeling that the Conda dependency of PyCall is causing some `libpython` issue, and that the `ENV["PYCALL_JL_RUNTIME_PYTHON"]` call doesn't override the libpython variable properly.

Comment: You have installed different Python-versions on your computer. Maybe you should uninstall all of them, then install only one of them (perhaps the latest stable version).

Comment: Thanks for replying; I'm not entirely convinced that's the case here. I only have 1 system python version installed, and it's python 3.7. The `libpython` version seems to want to point to `python3 exe` within the Julia directory (see the error in my post). I don't have conda installed on my system; this is one of the dependencies of PyCall (I believe).

Comment: In the quoted messages both python36.dll and python37.dll is mentioned. Maybe one of your programs came with a "built in Python" of version 3.6.x and that causes the version incompatibilty.

Comment: There are indeed 2 dlls. One is from a conda directory that's automatically installed when `Pkg.build("PyCall")` [is run, as shown here](https://imgur.com/a/4Arr6KT). If I get rid of this conda directory in the .julia home folder, Julia provides a non-specific error, then crashes.

Comment: Note that I ran `Pkg.build("PyCall")` after doing the python environment export; the error still persists. I'll update my original post to reflect that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation `PyCall` supports **`venv`** and **`virtualenv`** environments, but you are using `pipenv`. I recommend you try with either of the supported alternatives, if you want to use the `PYCALL_JL_RUNTIME_PYTHON` variable.

If you want to use continue using the `pipenv` environment instead, you probably have to specify the `PYTHON` variable instead in your `startup.jl` configuration file, like this:

```rb
ENV["PYTHON"] = "C:\\path\\to\\your\\pipenv\\python.exe"
```

Then run:

```rb
julia> using Pkg; Pkg.build("PyCall"); using PyCall
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I managed to get it working. It seems that the part of the readme that I was following - the change to `ENV["PYCALL_JL_RUNTIME_PYTHON"]` - was more about switching virtual environments after a build instead of setting up the python environment to begin with.